# Which book is set in a giant spaceship that can create life?

Tags: story-identification

I read a book about a group of travellers who discover a ship that is 30km long (I am not sure about the length of the ship).

The ship belonged to a race who were researchers. The ship can create life from some dna samples in the ship, I remember a tyrannosaurus rex being created and killing one of the characters.

The main character was a bald man who likes cats.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you read it?  What language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title.

Comment: Also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/140257/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are likely remembering George RR Martin's [Tuf Voyaging](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?16553). The characters find an abandoned genetic engineering warship. The ship has extensive gene banks. One of the stories does indeed have a T-rex or similar creature in it. The protagonist Haviland Tuf is bald and likes cats.

More from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuf_Voyaging):

> The novel concerns the (mis)adventures of Haviland Tuf, an
> exceptionally tall, bald, very pale, overweight, phlegmatic,
> vegetarian, cat-loving but otherwise solitary space trader. Due to the
> venality and cutthroat tactics of the party chartering his one-man
> trading vessel, Tuf inadvertently becomes master of Ark, an ancient,
> 30-kilometer-long "seedship", a very powerful warship with advanced
> ecological engineering capabilities. Tuf travels the galaxy, offering
> his services to worlds with environmental problems, and sometimes
> imposing solutions of his own.

[image]

Comment: Oh. My. Goodness. That is the best book cover I have ever seen. My how GRR Martin has fallen since the 80's...

Comment: The actual copy I own has a much better cover.  http://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/a/a8/TFVYGNG191986.jpg  Someone edited this one in and I, too, found it hilarious.

Comment: Lonely space cat man is also a fantastic cover. The book sounds interesting, but I almost don't want to ruin these hilarious images in my head by actually reading it.

Comment: So the main character creates animals that kill his friends and try repeatedly to take over his empire?

Comment: Note that *Tuf Voyaging* originally appeared as a series of short stories in *Analog*.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly the 1980 [Dragonstar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonstar_(science_fiction_series)) series by David Bischoff and Thomas Monteleone?

Points that match are that it has a long spaceship habitat serving as a DNA terrarium of reptilian and other types of life. The scene with a T-Rex being created and killing someone occurs in both the first two books of the series.  An excerpt from the first book is below along with the Covers of the books if any of those look familiar.

I don't remember the main character liking cats. At least not in the first book of the series.

Good luck.

> Day of the Dragonstar
>   Book One of the Dragonstar Series
>   by David Bischoff and Thomas F. Monteleone
>
> An artificial Jurassic world spins through space, kilometers long and made to order, build to endure for an eternity. An enticing mystery for the humans of the Heinlein exploratory mission, it holds deadly secrets from the universe's savage past.
>
> INSIDE THE MILES-LONG SPACESHIP IT WAS 160 MILLION YEARS AGO ...
>
> Day after artificial day, outwitting the carnivorous saurians that had devoured their shipmates, the two survivors of the Heinlein expedition to the mysterious object known as Artifact One picked their way through the vast, horizonless jungle that filled the hull of the star-traveling terrerium.
>
> They did what a man and a woman fighting together to survive usually do:
>   They prayed for rescue.
>   They searched for a way to escape.
>   They fell in love
>
> Then, from a rise in the forest, they saw a wall.
>   And something on the wall saw them.
>
> THE SENTRY
>
> Atop a crumbling rampart stood a sentry, weapon grasped in its four-fingered hand, partly clothed ... its snout instintively twitching at the scent of the man and woman walking toward its city.

[Cover1](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/b/david-f-bischoff/day-of-dragonstar.htm)

[Cover2](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/b/david-f-bischoff/night-of-dragonstar.htm)

[Cover3](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/b/david-f-bischoff/dragonstar-destiny.htm)